# Script manager won't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, scriptmanager

I have a master page and their is script manager with update panel inside it. . now i am trying to add update panel in content page without using script manager but it gives me an error:

```
The control with ID 'updpanel' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.
```

I know i can use only one instance of script manager, then i tried **ScriptManagerProxy** but it gives me the error that scriptMangerProxy requires script manager.
I also tried ajax:ToolScriptManager but it also gives the same results
So the question is how can make the update panel to work in content page..

**Master Page:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SideMaster.master.cs" Inherits="SideMaster" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#chit').scrollTop(1000000);

        });
</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<div class="sidemenu">
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="topNav" runat="server" />

        <asp:Menu ID="SideMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="topNav" CssClass="SideMenu" StaticDisplayLevels="4"
          Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="20" IncludeStyleBlock="true"  >
         <StaticMenuItemStyle VerticalPadding="5" BackColor="#670a0a" ForeColor="White" HorizontalPadding="5" />
         <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#670a0a" />
        </asp:Menu>
</div>

<div class="cont3" >
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

<div class="rightmenu">

<div class="newspan">

<asp:Repeater ID="RepNews" runat="server" >
<HeaderTemplate><div class="newsheadcont">News & Events</div></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="newstemp">
<hr />
&#35; &nbsp; <%#Eval("News") %>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkNews" runat="server" CssClass="welcomeMore"></asp:LinkButton>

</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>

<br /><br />

<div class="chatcont" style="margin-left:1%;">
<div class="chat">
<h2 class="chathead">Peoples Talking About </h2>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scmang" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <%--<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        xPos = $get('chit').scrollLeft;
        yPos = $get('chit').scrollTop;
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $get('chit').scrollLeft = xPos;
        $get('chit').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanelChat" runat="server"  ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" >

<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="pan" runat="server">
<asp:ListView ID="ListChat" runat="server"  >
<LayoutTemplate>
<div class="chattemp" style="width:250px;  " id="chit" >



<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemSeparatorTemplate><hr /></ItemSeparatorTemplate>
<EmptyDataTemplate>No Data Found</EmptyDataTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="chatbox" >

<div class="chatpic" style="margin:18px 0px 0px 0px;" >
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageChat" runat="server" 
 ToolTip='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' 
    ImageUrl='<%# "~/ShowImage.ashx?Name=" + Server.UrlEncode(Eval("UserName").ToString()) %>'
        PostBackUrl='<%#"~/Profile/Profile.aspx?Name="+Eval("UserName") %>'
         Width="50" Height="50" />
</div>

<div class="chatbubble" style="width:160px; margin:-50px 5px 5px 60px; float:left;">
<asp:Label ID="LabelChat" runat="server" Width="100" Height="50"><%#Eval("Body") %></asp:Label>
</div>

<div class="chatname" style="width:50px; border:none;" >
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkUserName" runat="server"  
PostBackUrl='<%#"~/Profile/Profile.aspx?Name="+Eval("UserName") %>'><%#Eval("UserName") %></asp:LinkButton>
</div>

</div>



</ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
<asp:Timer ID="TimerUpdate" runat="server" Interval="20000" 
        ontick="TimerUpdate_Tick"></asp:Timer>
        </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<div class="messagebox" style="width:250px; height:120px; border:none;">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMessage" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Visible="false" Width="250" Height="80" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonMessage" runat="server" Text="Comment" 
        onclick="ButtonMessage_Click" Visible="false" />
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>

</asp:Content>
```

**Content Page:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<div class="interface" >
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<div class="goog">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkFind" runat="server" CssClass="linkgoog">Find</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</td></tr>

<tr><td align="left">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearch" runat="server" Width="600" Height="40"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" Text="SEARCH" CssClass="loginbt" 
        onclick="ButtonSearch_Click1" /><br />

</div>

</td></tr>

</table>
</div>

    <br />
    <div class="interface">


    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridAll" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="GridAll_ItemCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="10" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3" OnPageIndexChanging="GridAll_PageIndexChanging" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#670a0a" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="20">
    <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server"
             Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'
              PostBackUrl='<%#"~/Profile/Profile.aspx?Name="+Eval("UserName") %>' CssClass="welcomeMore"/>

            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#670a0a" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="20" >
    <ItemTemplate>
    <span class="googtext"><%#Eval("Department") %></span>
         </ItemTemplate>       
    </asp:TemplateField>



    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#670a0a" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="20">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <span class="googtext"><%#Eval("Year") %></span>
         </ItemTemplate>       
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Photo" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#670a0a" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="20">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="ImageProfile" runat="server" ImageUrl = '<%# "~/ShowImage.ashx?Name=" + Server.UrlEncode(Eval("UserName").ToString()) %>' Width="150" Height="150" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <div class="emptytext">No Match Found</div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Your help will be appreciated. . . Thank you

Comment: please show the actually code from your master page and the content page. You probably have you hide the script manager some how. You do not need to include the script manager on the content page, is only must exist some where on the page.

Comment: Just place the `asp:ScriptManager` upper, right after header on the first master page because I believe this is a nested master page. Also move the script that you use more up.

Answer (score 1):

You should have only one script manager in master page above update panel.

In any of the content page you can use update panel as there is already script manager in master page. Also you should provide some code for your problem.

Comment: You can ONLY have one script manager on a page, which is why a lot of solutions use it in the master page, thus content pages just use that script manager.